# Seeing an issue within my code and having other issues recognized

Tags: javascript

The CMD window is posting
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1>node revers~2.js
events.js:160

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open  
'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1\Input_File.txt'
at Error (native)
```

I don't know what it may be referencing but I believe that it may be part of the `Node.js` software that I am using to run my code.

Thank you for any help that you are able to provide. I'm sorry if this question seems basic or kinda self explanatory, I just can't see the issue.

It might also be that I do not have the proper kind of code to preform this task.

The `Input_File.txt` has

```
15 12 2 + -4 * + 3 -
```

data in it. I don't know if this will help in any way. This is the Reverse Polish Function that I am attempting to have the program solve.

```
'use strict' ;

var ArrayStack = require ( './ArrayStack' ) ;
const fs = require ( 'fs' ) ;
const readline = require ( 'readline' ) ;

var ArrayStack2 = new ArrayStack () ;
var readStream = fs.createReadStream ( 'Input_File.txt', 'utf8' ) ;
var rl = readline.createInterface ( {input:readStream} ) ;
rl.on ('line', function (inputLine)
            {
            console.log(inputLine) ;
            var tokens =  inputline.split( ' ' ) ;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < tokens.length ; i ++ )
                {
                const token = tokens[i] ;
                var tokenCategory = 'operand' ;
                if ( token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*' ) 
                {
                    tokenCategory = 'operator' ;
                    var B = ArrayStack2.pop() ;
                    var A = ArrayStack2.pop() ;
                    if ( token === '+' )
                    {
                        var answer = A + B ;
                        ArrayStack2.push(answer) ;
                                            }
                    elseif ( token === '-' )
                    {
                        var answer = A - B ;
                        ArrayStack2.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '/' )
                    {
                        var answer = A / B ;
                        ArrayStack2.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '*' )
                    {
                        var answer = A * B ;
                        ArrayStack2.push(answer) ;
                    }//end of sub conditional statement

                }//end of if statement
                else 
                {
                    ArrayStack2.push(token) ;
                    console.log (ArrayStack) ;
                }
              }//end of for loop

            });//end of function  

            rl.on ( 'close', function () {
            console.log('File now closed.');
            }) ; // end function
```

This is the ArrayStack class that is being used to store the data and then solve the problem.

```
'use strict' ;

var EmptyError = require( './EmptyError' ) ;

class ArrayStack
    {

    constructor ( )
        {
        // An empty array added as a "private" property of the stack.
        // Objects pushed onto the stack will be stored in this array.
        this._data = new Array() ;
        } // end constructor

    isEmpty ( )
        {
        return ( this._data.length === 0 ) ;
        } // end isEmpty

    push ( toPush )
        {
        this._data.push( toPush ) ;
        return this ;
        } // end push

    pop ( )
        {
        if ( this.isEmpty() )
            throw new EmptyError("Can't pop from an empty stack!") ;
        return this._data.pop( ) ;
        } // end pop

    top ( )
        {
        if ( this.isEmpty() )
            throw new EmptyError('An empty stack has no top!') ;
        return this._data [ this._data.length - 1 ] ;
        } // end top

    len ( )
        {
        return this._data.length ;
        } // end len

    } // end ArrayStack class

module.exports = ArrayStack ;
```

This is the Empty Error class that is being used in reference to the ArrayStack class.

```
'use strict' ;

class EmptyError extends Error
    {
    constructor ( message )
        {
        // Ask superclass' constructor to initialize this object,
        // including creating its "message" property ...
        super ( message ) ;
        } // end constructor
    } // end EmptyError class

module.exports = EmptyError ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`'operator' === '-'` and so on is a string comparasion , In no way `operator` is same as `-`,`/`,`*`

Though not tested , I think you have compare with the `token` but not with operator

```
if (token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*'); {
  //Rest of code
  if (token === '+') {
} else if (token === '-') {
    // rest of code
  }
// rest of code
}
```

Comment: Ohh...I didn't even think of it that way, since I'm actually just having it check there but not actually reassigning the value anywhere. Thank you!!!

Comment: C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1>node revers~2.js
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1\revers~2.js:37
                                        else if ( 'token' === '-' )

This is what the CMD window is printing when I attempt to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out basic if-else brackets. And as @brk says, you are comparing two strings
'operator' and '+', '-' etc
Here is the updated code. Check if this works for you.

```
'use strict' ; 

var ArrayStack = require ( './ArrayStack' ) ;
const fs = require ( 'fs' ) ;
const readline = require ( 'readline' ) ;

new ArrayStack () ;
var readStream = fs.createReadStream ( 'Input_File.txt', 'utf8' ) ;
var rl = readline.createInterface ( {input:readStream} ) ;
rl.on ('line', function (inputLine)
            {
            console.log(inputLine) ;
            var tokens =  inputline.split( ' ' ) ;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < tokens.length ; i ++ )
                {
                const token = tokens[i] ;
                var tokenCategory = 'operand' ;
                if ( token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*' ) 
                {
                    tokenCategory = 'operator' ;
                    var B = ArrayStack.pop() ;
                    var A = ArrayStack.pop() ;
                    if ( token === '+' )
                    {
                        var answer = A + B ;
                        ArrayStack.push(answer) ;
//the error shows here where CMD recognizes the else as an 'unexpected token' 
//have I missed something in setting up my nesting properly? 
                                            }
                    elseif ( token === '-' )
                    {
                        var answer = A - B ;
                        ArrayStack.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '/' )
                    {
                        var answer = A / B ;
                        ArrayStack.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '*' )
                    {
                        var answer = A * B ;
                        ArrayStack.push(answer) ;
                    }//end of sub conditional statement

                }//end of if statement
                else 
                {
                    ArrayStack.push(token) ;
                    console.log (ArrayStack) ;
                }
              }//end of for loop

            });//end of function  


            rl.on ( 'close', function () {
            console.log('File now closed.');
            }) ; // end function
```

I do not know how your text file works here. But I have updated your code with few changes. You can try this one.

```
var ArrayStack = require ( './ArrayStack' ) ;
const fs = require ( 'fs' ) ;
const readline = require ( 'readline' ) ;

var myStack
var readStream = fs.createReadStream ( 'Input_File.txt', 'utf8' ) ;
var rl = readline.createInterface ( {input:readStream} ) ;
rl.on ('line', function (inputLine)
            {
            console.log(inputLine) ;
            var tokens =  inputLine.split( ' ' ) ;
            ArrayStack.init(tokens, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error received');
    }
    else {
         myStack = data;
        console.log('pushed data '+data.first());

    }
});                 
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < tokens.length ; i ++ )
                {
                const token = tokens[i] ;
                var tokenCategory = 'operand' ;
                if ( token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*' ) 
                {
                    tokenCategory = 'operator' ;
                    var B = myStack.pop();
                    var A = myStack.pop();
                    if ( token === '+' )
                    {
                        var answer = A + B ;
                        myStack.push(answer) ;
                                            }
                    elseif ( token === '-' )
                    {
                        var answer = A - B ;
                        myStack.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '/' )
                    {
                        var answer = A / B ;
                        myStack.push(answer) ;
                    }
                    elseif ( token === '*' )
                    {
                        var answer = A * B ;
                        myStack.push(answer) ;
                    }//end of sub conditional statement

                }//end of if statement
                else 
                {
                    myStack.push(token) ;
                    console.log (myStack) ;
                }
              }//end of for loop
            });//end of function  

            rl.on ( 'close', function () {
            console.log('File now closed.');
            }) ; // end function
```

Comment: If I attempt that version, the CMD shows 

C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1>node revers~2
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Is there another place to look for the error?

Comment: Which is line 160? Can you add fiddle or something for test?

Comment: I don't have that many lines in the code, so it has to be referencing something that is from Node.js. Since that is the software that I am using to run the program through.

Comment: Does the text file you have specified exists at proper path? You also need to debug per line to find the issue, since there is no test version online to test for us.

Comment: The text file is within the same directory and should be able to be pulled from that directory, if I am understanding my code properly.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to find the issue that was present though. My laptop does not show the file extensions and when I imported the Input_File.txt into my directory for usage it was renamed to Input_File.txt.txt. Therefore causing the error to be thrown that the file didn't exist since it had been improperly named. Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `else` is an "unexpected token" is because you're not using `{` and `}` correctly with your `if`/`else if`/`else` structure.

The correct syntax is:

```
if (condition) {
  statement1
} else if (condition) {
  statement2
} else {
  statement3
}
```

...where the curly brackets `{` and `}` are optional if you want to use a *single* statement, but *required* if you want the block to contain multiple statements.

In your code, each of the `if` and `else if` blocks contains two lines, so you have to surround them with `{` and `}`.

Also, on the following line:

```
if ( token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*' ) ;
```

...the semicolon at the end means there is *no* statement executed if the `if` condition is true, even though you start the next line with a `{`.

If you fix all of the curly brackets up you'd end up with something like this:

```
function (inputLine) {
  console.log(inputLine);
  var tokens = inputline.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    const token = tokens[i];
    var tokenCategory = 'operand';
    if (token === '+' || token === '-' || token === '/' || token === '*') {
      tokenCategory = 'operator';
      var B = ArrayStack.pop();
      var A = ArrayStack.pop();
      if (token === '+') {
        var answer = A + B;
        ArrayStack.push(answer);
      } else if (token === '-') {
        var answer = A - B;
        ArrayStack.push(answer);
      } else if (token === '/') {
        var answer = A / B;
        ArrayStack.push(answer);
      } else if (token === '*') {
        var answer = A * B;
        ArrayStack.push(answer);
      } //end of sub conditional statement
    } //end of if statement
    else {
      ArrayStack.push(token);
      console.log(ArrayStack);
    }
  } //end of for loop    
} //end of function
```

(Noting that you can put the curly brackets on their own line if you prefer.)

Also where you were comparing the string `'operator'` you probably wanted the variable `token`.

Comment: With those issues being resolved, the CMD prints 

C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1>node revers~2.js
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1\revers~2.js:64
                        }//end of function

Is there something else that I am missing?? If I compare the braces then they all match up.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the line `new ArrayStack ();` looks suspicious because you don't assign the result to a variable and then later you call `ArrayStack.pop()` and `ArrayStack.push()` directly on the `ArrayStack` constructor function rather than on an instance. I haven't used that `ArrayStack` before myself, but I would've expected something like `var arraystack = new ArrayStack();` and then later in the function use that variable with `arraystack.push()` and `arraystack.pop()`. I'm not sure what `ArrayStack` is supposed to give you that a plain array wouldn't in this scenario.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue and it is now showing me 

C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1>node revers~2.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\PROGRA~1\I
nput_File.txt'
    at Error (native)

I'm not seeing what it is that is causing the error, if all of the code is matching up better than it was earlier.

Comment: Well "no such file or directory" is obviously occurring at a point where you try to access the filesystem, so presumably on the `fs.createReadStream(...` line. Does the specified file exist? Is Node defaulting to looking in a different directory than what you expect it to?

Comment: I am unsure of how Node would be able to default into somewhere else, and the text file that I am examining within the program exists within the same directory that the code is being stored in.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not really a Node guy, but maybe it defaults to the folder Node is installed in. Try specifying a complete file path in your code rather than just the filename.

Comment: If I put ./Input_File.txt inside of that line it still attempts  to throw that error. Since the ./ has it check inside of the same directory, correct?

Comment: Probably the same directory as wherever it already thinks it's looking. Try the *complete* path, `c:\whatever\applies\here\Input_File.txt`. (Even if you don't want to have to do that in a general sense, at least it would be something you can test to help diagnose the problem.)

Comment: I'm going to visit with a professor at the University tomorrow. I think that is my next step, having another set of eyes see it and possibly bring a new perspective. Thank you for your assistance. Also, it is still throwing the error after I put in the complete file path. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: I managed to find the issue. Since my laptop does not show the file extensions, when I imported the Input_File.txt into the directory for use, it became misnamed to Input_File.txt.txt and that would cause the error since it couldn't find the actual file within the directory because it was looking for a file that did not actually exist. Thank you for all your help and assistance though.